# Compare URL access with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have a bunch of URLs of the form https://sensr.net/cameras/...  Sometimes the suffix is an integer, sometimes it's text.

For example:

- https://sensr.net/cameras/88
- https://sensr.net/cameras/columbine-lake-webcam
- https://sensr.net/cameras/ap-cam1--2

I would like to find a way in GA to find which of these URLs are most popular.  Is there some way to track URLs of a specific form in GA for comparison?

Answer (score 2):

you can check the page performance using "All Pages" report. The report placed in "Behavior >> Site Content".

Once you open the report you can see all the pages and some metrics. Based on these metrics you can measure the performance.

Ex: If people read and stay on more time in some pages than other pages, those pages we can assume as quality pages. Measure the above situation using "Pageviews" and "Avg.Time.On Page  " metrics.

If people are leaving the pages or the web site quickly, that mean you need to give attention to those pages.Maybe the content is not relevant or not have enough content to get user engagement. Use "Bounce Rate" metric to measure this. if you have a higher bounce rate that mean page performance are poor.

Refer this link for more infor: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2404517?hl=en&ref_topic=1120718

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  I am seeing duplicates though, the urls for the same camera with different parameters, /cameras/34525?interval=hour&imgid=xxx versus /cameras/34525?interval=hour&imgid=yyy.  Any idea how to collapse these?

Comment: In this case what I do, I download the data as a CSV file and open it using MS Excel. Then removing the unnecessary parts using "Find and Replace" option. Use Pivot Tables to get the summery, and you are done with less than 5 minutes :)> .